# How to see the chatbot users count in AppInsights in Azure portal

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I have developed a chatbot using node js in Azure portal, I would like to see the total number of users accessed my chatbot in portal

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Access the **Analytics** section in Application Insights >> Overview. Here you can write queries to get app/bot related data.

This query returns the **number of users per channel**. 
You should adjust the time as you like (don't forget about the timezones), or remove them altogether to use the apps time range.

```
customEvents
| where timestamp > todatetime('2018-10-01T15:30:00.000Z')
| where timestamp < todatetime('2018-10-23T15:30:00.000Z')
| where name == 'MBFEvent.UserMessage' 
| summarize dcount(tostring(customDimensions.conversationId)) by tostring(customDimensions.channel)
```

Following is the output of the query
[image]

You can adjust the query for **number of total users across channels** using

```
| summarize dcount(tostring(customDimensions.conversationId))
```

The same info can also be found in **Analytics** section of the bot registration page (image shown below shows data for a different date range)

[image]

You can try changing the date range in Bot Registration page's analytics section and using the same date range in the query to verify the number of users.

[image]

Comment: ya i have seen the added answer just now, i checked the analytics section, the problem is it shows me only 11 users, but the bot has been accessing since last september. Even i tried the query given by you, it fetches 4k records. But the count in the analytics log section and result from query has huge difference –

Comment: Bot Registration page's **Analytics** log section show data for a maximum date range of 90 days. Have you tried changing the date range?

Comment: ya,checked but still it gives the same count.