# How to find the users count in app insights

Tags: azure, botframework

I have developed a chat bot in Microsoft bot framework in node js. I want to see the total users count who have accessed my chat bot through directline and webchannel through app insights in Azure portal. And I want to confirm if the From ID is the unique ID of an user who is accessing my bot.
I tried this query to get the users count.

customEvents
|where timestamp >ago(7d)
|summarize count() by tostring(customDimensions["From ID"])

The following are the results I got

[image: result]

In the image the highlighted one is my bot and I got a count but if its correct as i am getting count of other things as well.

Can some body help. Thank you

Comment: did you try summarize count() by user_id or user_AccountId ??

Comment: now i tried summarize count() by user_id , it gives me some number, but in my custom dimensions i don't have user_id. i have conversation id, from id, activity id, channel id, bot id only.

Comment: hmm. userid works for applications which have users authenticated via azure AD etc I believe.

Comment: Is this a duplicate question? Just added an answer from the same user in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52930193/how-to-see-the-chatbot-users-count-in-appinsights-in-azure-portal/52946419#52946419)

Comment: ya i have seen the added answer just now, i checked the analytics section, the problem is it shows me only 11 users, but the bot has been accessing since last september. Even i tried the query given by you, it fetches 4k records. But the count in the analytics log section and result from query has huge difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see the chatbot users count in AppInsights in Azure portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52930193/how-to-see-the-chatbot-users-count-in-appinsights-in-azure-portal)